# Setting custom xml layout for action bar as theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to have my custom layout action bar to be shown right as the activity starts,

Currently the default actionbar is shown for a second or two before I set the custom view for the action bar.

Currently i'm doing it this way :

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

And it works, but the default action bar is shown for a few seconds.

How can I set the custom xml layout as a style ?

Comment: try with my answer @user1940676

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP before starting the intent has helped.

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add onemore line to you code.

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.abs_title);
```

Comment: doesn't work when the onCreate takes more time to load.
It still shows the default action bar for a second or two.